# Auto Refill Pot with Water as Liquid Evaporates

Tags: water, faucet, home-automation, hose

I have a Instant Pot operating 24/7 without the lid. The water in the pot slowly evaporates from the heat and if I do not refill the water every couple of hours it will completely evaporate and burn the pot. I am not able to babysit the pot and refill it manually when the water level drops too low.

Attaching one end of a metal hose to a faucet and placing the other end in the pot will obviously not work, since it would cause the water in the pot to overflow as there is no way to control the flow of water from faucet to pot with any level of precision.

I have toyed around with several ideas such as using a [Auto-Fill Water Bowl](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00RAQBHAO) however the way this product is designed there's no way for it to detect low water level in a pot and automatically refill it - it is designed to work only for animals (the end is also plastic so I can't put it in a pot of boiling water).

I've also toyed with a [Mechanical](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006FLGHGE) and [Smart](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01D1NMLJU) Water Timer but the product can only turn the water on/off at preset intervals. Since I cannot precisely control the amount of water that flows through the timer, there's no way to control delivery of water to pot with precision.

It might be possible to design a system by borrowing some of the principles behind the [Self-Dispensing Gravity Waterer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07227RQJ9) however the way the product is currently designed, it is not a viable solution.

Any other advice or ideas on how to modify aforementioned products so that it solves my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem. Forget the Instant Pot for a minute. **What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?** Humidity? Steam?

Comment: @manassehkatz-ReinstateMonica Humidity.

Comment: So essentially you are looking for a "self filling humidifier". A quick Google search on those terms provides some options. Unfortunately, commercial products of this type are not cheap. Building something is possible, but not trivial as you're dealing with both electricity and water.

Comment: @manassehkatz-ReinstateMonica No, I've looked into other humidifiers and this is the only option that suits my needs. Most of the humidifiers available work via ultrasonic mist, not through evaporation. Besides, as you mentioned the "self filling humidifier" are expensive. Even if there was something available that worked through evaporation, I'm still **highly** interested in an answer to this question as I will not be using any other product besides the Instant Pot to humidify my home.. Thanks!

Comment: turn a large water filled bottle upside down into the pot

Comment: get a steam humidifier ... it automatically shuts down when empty

Comment: @jsotola the boiling water won't melt the water bottle? Won't it cause the water in the pot to overflow? Thanks!

Comment: no idea ... try it with a large soft drink bottle ... hang it upside down using a string ... put the pot on the floor and hang the bottle from a table

Comment: The upside down water bottle won't work.  To move water around in a controlled manner, you always wind up needing pumps and/or valves.

Comment: An upside down bottle will work to increase the time before manual intervention is required .  For instance, you might only need to fill the system every 12 hours instead of every 3 hours.  Glass bottles will not melt.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Rube Goldberg.

Comment: However, A mechanism like the one that avoids overfilling in self refilling water reservoirs may work. I have seen ones where the float is made from coper-like metal instead of plastic. These have the float at the end of a bronze rod. The rod simply operates a valve, closing it when it reaches certain level.

Answer (score 3):

We often get cases where a person becomes [fixated](https://youtu.be/Bd8_vO5zrjo?t=2182) on one method, and loses sight of the big picture/overall purpose of the exercise. (This often manifests as the "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)").  Your goal *is not* to abuse an Instant Pot; it's to humidify your home.  Step back.

### You're ready to spend money. Just buy the right thing.

You've plainly stated that you're ready to spend $30+++ on various apparatus to try to solve this.  The money you're willing to spend is much more than a *proper* humidifier actually costs.  So just buy one of those. If you can't bear to spend $30, then go to the Salvation Army store and spend $5.

If you don't like *misting* humidifiers, there are lots of other kinds.  Misting has the advantage of a very sensible power draw, because it's not heating the water, it's letting your house's normal furnace do that more efficiently.

### This is a firestarter at so many levels

NEC 110.3(B) says you must obey equipment's labeling and instructions.  An Instant Pot is a kitchen appliance, specifically a pressure cooker with computer controls.  It does many things, but *humidifying is not one of them*. It is not labeled for that, which means UL didn't *test* for that, which means it's not a safe appliance for that purpose.

What happens when it runs dry is a case in point. **Instant Pots aren't designed to run dry** where they would go into thermal runaway. There is no conceivable listed use of an Instant Pot where it would ever run dry, since operations are supposed to be on a timer or monitor. *You are defeating those features to make it possible to misuse*.

Further, using it "way off-label" like this, will greatly shorten the unit's life.  Smoke the unit, and suddenly the "big savings" from avoiding a proper humidifier go up in smoke.

There are many other issues when it's used outside of a kitchen, but you say not.

### The Instant Pot *already* has a shutoff feature

Because the [latent heat of vaporization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_vaporization) is not a surprise.

And **the Instant Pot has a timer** and a known rate of heating.

- You already know (or reasonably should know) the electric power consumption of your Instant Pot.  Yours will say, but my guess is 1500 watts, because that is the maximum allowed for a plug-in kitchen appliance under UL listing rules.
- The latent heat of vaporization of water is 2264.705 joules per gram.
- A joule is 1 watt for 1 second. (wow, that's easy)
- That means that the Instant Pot makes 1500* joules per second

* Your value actually goes here.

Now you can compute: in my example it takes 2264 / 1500* = 1.51 seconds for the Instant Pot to boil 1 gram of water.

- 1000 grams makes 1 kilogram.
- 1 litre of water weighs 1 kilogram (not a coincidence)
- A litre is basically a quart (good enough for this).

So 1 litre = 1 quart = 1kg = 1000 grams = 1000 times as long as a gram, so that makes (in my example) 1510 sec. = 25 minutes.  Per litre.

So if you have a 10 litre pot, that's 250 minutes or 4:10.

***Now you know how to set the timer on the Instant Pot***.

This will finish with some water left over, because we're ignoring inefficiency and the *specific heat* required to raise the water from tap temperature (15C?) to boiling temperature. That is small potatoes compared to latent heat of vaporization, and you need a little safety margin anyway.

Also, you should be dumping out the last 20% of the water, because it has 5 times the mineral concentration of normal water, and if you boil it dry, it will leave mineral deposits on your Instant Pot.  That mineral action can actually etch stainless.  That's one problem that misting dehumidifiers solve (they throw the minerals into the air).

Honestly, since the Instant Pot is so computerized, I'm amazed they allow *any* mode where enough joules could be added to evaporate all the water. It makes me wonder if you're tricking the computer to do this.

What a bad idea.

### Metering water like you want is a rather hard problem

The crux of the problem being to stop overflows/runaways *with a high level of reliability*.  That is why you're not finding easy, off-the-shelf solutions to it.  Finding one that works at boiling-water temperatures is even harder.

Comment: Thanks! There's some very good info in this answer but most of the dangers you mentioned are based on incorrect assumptions as the device is being used on a kitchen countertop in a safe and secure environment.  No extension cord needed. Also, if you could find me a heat (evaporative) humidifier for under $30 (or even $50 or $70) please let me know. To my knowledge such a device does not exist. You mentioned the possibility of buying a mist humidifier but this is precisely what I'm  trying to avoid.. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that's why you can't find them. This fixation I mentioned is causing you to fail to see them in product listings, as it caused you to miss much of what I said, including that there are plenty of non-misting units out there.  One point I failed to mention: you will quickly wear out this Instant Pot doing this, even if you stop boiling it dry. So you shouldn't be comparing the cost of a proper humidifier to $30, but to the cost of another Instant Pot. Or two!

Comment: [Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=warm+mist+humidifier&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwif4-aF4pfmAhUOI6wKHbSFAhoQ_AUoAXoECAwQAw&biw=874&bih=1107) *loads in the $30s.*

Comment: Good answer @Harper-ReinstateMonica and I agree, but one small correction: the Instant Pot (at least the one I have) actually does have protection for thermal runaway.  If you let it boil dry, the Instant Pot will show "burn" on the display and shut off the heating element.  Though I still wouldn't recommend using it as a humidifier for all the other reasons you mention.

Comment: There are a lot of assumptions here, although I agree with the answer in spirit. The concern about minerals concentrating is valid, even if the pot is continuously filled. I don't really see too much danger to life and limb here, considering it's an open system as opposed to a closed boiler and assuming the pot has a (non-electronic) thermal cut-off (although I would never recommend running it unattended). My Granny used to leave a pot on the boil for hours...

Answer (score 1):

You could likely rig something using a float valve. They make pretty small ones that you could supply with tubing. They are available with metal floats too.

These are very common for household, commercial, and industrial applications. In fact, visit any farm with livestock and you will probably see a larger size one in action, to keep livestock watering troughs full. They are also used to maintain the water level in swamp coolers, google-fu around and you will find one that will work.

[image]

Comment: Probably also a good idea to install some sort of over-temperature protection in the heater, in case the fill valve or water supply fails.

Comment: I don't see any way this isn't a firestarter, or at best a floodstarter.  OP is trying to Macgyver something that's actually pretty hard.

Comment: This was my first thought and I have used one to keep a coffee maker filled, but not sure if they make them to handle boiling water.

Comment: Metal rod and float would be fine in boiling water...

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly common thing to do for espresso or even pod-type coffee machines that come standard with a water tank. A lot of people desire to have the tank fill itself without having to manually remember to fill it all the time. So if you search for something like "Espresso Machine Tank Fill Valve", you will find some instructions and examples of what people have done.
[One quick example](https://www.home-barista.com/espresso-machines/quit-filling-that-water-tank-t229.html), which uses components bought from the hardware store for the most part.

Searching for "coffee machine float valve kit" yields pre-made float valves that shut off the water when a certain level is reached, for example [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1-4-Mini-Adjustable-Float-Valve-for-Keurig-or-Coffee-Machine-Self-Filling-Water-/201947447935).

Comment: +1, I am now committed to installing one on my Keurig, floods be damned...!